# How to enable "clickfinger" settings interactively to test behavior?

Tags: xorg, touchpad

I am configuring a new laptop with a trackpad which lacks any physical buttons. Out of box I am not able to right click. This has made it surprisingly difficult to research and keep notes about all the problems remaining to fix on my installation.

I read that I can use the `xinput` utility with `libinput` to change the settings for my touchpad.

```
xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "libinput Click Method Enabled" 1 0
```

I don't understand how to interpret `1 0`. It looks like a binary code, possibly for `2`. In the `libinput` documentation it mentions there are three settings: none, side areas, and clickfinger. This suggests that `3` might be the right version. `1 1` appears to be out of bounds. That actually makes sense in terms of C integer counting starting from 0. By this reasoning `1 0` should be the configuration I want, but the effect is not showing up. I cannot right click to copy and past text in the browser, which is my main use case.

I also tried to change the direction of scrolling with:

```
xinput --set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

Again, I had no luck.

Is this just impossible to experiment with interactively or is there some other command I need?

Answer (score 1):

At least on my Debian 11, `man 4 libinput` documents the click method properties like this:

> **libinput Click Methods Available**
>
> 2 boolean values (8 bit, 0 or 1), in order "buttonareas", "clickfinger".  Indicates which click methods are available on this device.
>
> **libinput Click Methods Enabled**
>
> 2 boolean values (8 bit, 0 or 1), in order "buttonareas", "clickfinger".  Indicates which click methods are enabled on this device.

So the number values `1 0` would enable the "buttonareas" click method only, i.e. tapping on a specific areas of the touchpad would register as a click of the respective mouse button. That would be the side areas you mentioned. To enable the "clickfinger" method only, the values would have to be `0 1`.

This scheme enables the activation of either click method independently, both together, or none. Of course, the hardware might not support all possible combinations.

Your desktop environment might be managing the XInput settings, and overriding any changes you might be trying to make with the `xinput` command. Before resorting to command line, check any GUI settings utility your desktop environment has.

Also note that the man page on my system has the property name as "libinput Click Method**s** Enabled", but I assume that was probably just a typo in your question.